# visualization of multi dimensional data

Tags: python, r, ggplot2, data-visualization, seaborn

I have a pandas dataframe obtained by SQL aggregations over multiple columns similar to:

```
SELECT is_sick, age_group, sex, smoothing_kernel, state, count(*), median(value), mean(value)
FROM mytable
GROUP BY age_group, sex, smoothing_kernel, state, is_sick
```

This quickly results in a lot of categories. How can these be visualised without generating a mess of plots (incomprehensible)? I know faceting from ggplot, but this quickly results in a mess of charts when faceting over > 1 dimension. Are there better options available?

Comment: Maybe use some sort of dimensionality reduction technique such as PCA or t-SNE? It will result in a 2D plot that uses the information of all dimensions to make a visualization of each observation. An example in my field is the [Tumor Map](https://tumormap.ucsc.edu/) - a visualization of molecular characteristics of thousands of tumors with different cancer types.